# I can't connect to AD by "net ads join"(winbind)

Tags: centos, samba

I want to connect to Windows Active Directory from CentOS 7 with Samba, winbind.
Samba is already running but Winbind is not errored by following error at log.winbindd.

> ../source3/winbindd/winbindd_util.c:891(init_domain_list)
>
> Could not fetch our SID - did we join?

I try "net -d 10 ads join -S dcserver -U poweruser" then get error log.
what parameter is Invalid? what parameter ddidn't I write in my config?
I don't know "dn" written in this log.

```
kerberos_kinit_password: as poweruser@DMNAME.OURCO.JP using [MEMORY:libnet_join_user_creds] as ccache and config [/var/lib/samba/lock/smb_krb5/krb5.conf.DMNAME]
Starting GENSEC mechanism spnego
Starting GENSEC submechanism gse_krb5
gse_get_client_auth_token: Server principal not found
SPNEGO(gse_krb5) creating NEG_TOKEN_INIT for ldap/dcserver failed (next[(null)]): NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
Failed to setup SPNEGO negTokenInit request: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
kinit succeeded but ads_sasl_spnego_gensec_bind(KRB5) failed for ldap/dcserver with user[poweruser] realm[DMNAME.OURCO.JP]: An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.
ads_sasl_spnego_gensec_bind(KRB5) failed for ldap/dcserver with user[poweruser] realm=[DMNAME.OURCO.JP]: An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.
libnet_Join:
    libnet_JoinCtx: struct libnet_JoinCtx
        out: struct libnet_JoinCtx
            account_name             : 'MYCENTSV$'
            netbios_domain_name      : 'DMNAME'
            dns_domain_name          : 'dmname.OURCO.JP'
            forest_name              : 'dmname.OURCO.JP'
            dn                       : NULL
            domain_guid              : 4b8db2c2-43fd-4008-be4f-66ad75c21c2d
            domain_sid               : *
                domain_sid               : S-1-5-21-1645522239-789336058-839522115
            modified_config          : 0x00 (0)
            error_string             : 'failed to connect to AD: An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.'
            domain_is_ad             : 0x01 (1)
            set_encryption_types     : 0x00000000 (0)
            krb5_salt                : NULL
            result                   : WERR_NERR_DEFAULTJOINREQUIRED
Failed to join domain: failed to connect to AD: An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.
return code = -1
msg_dgm_ref_destructor: refs=(nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by myself.
I didn't know but "dcserver" was alias of "dcserver-1" in Active Directory.
So It works after I replace it "dcserver-1" - `net ads join -S dcserver-1 -U poweruser`!

I guess maybe "dcserver-1" is specified in ldap config, but because I have no right of Active Directory Administration, so I'm not sure.

Thanks.